# Hiding rows based on value in material table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'd like to know if there's a way to permanently hide rows based on value in Angular Material. Let's say I never want to show results when the value of name is "test". I was looking at using the .filterpredicate method but not sure if it's the best approach? Any help will is appreciated

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { BudgetService } from '../budget.service';
import { Record } from '../record.model';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-budget-list',
  templateUrl: './budget-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./budget-list.component.css']
})
export class BudgetListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'date', 'name', 'value', 'category', 'type', 'button']
  dataSource = this.service.dataSource;

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(public service: BudgetService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllReports();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  doFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
    import { BudgetService } from '../budget.service';
    import { Record } from '../record.model';
    import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-budget-list',
      templateUrl: './budget-list.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./budget-list.component.css']
    })
    export class BudgetListComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
      displayedColumns = ['id', 'date', 'name', 'value', 'category', 'type', 'button']
      dataSource = this.service.dataSource;
    
      @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
      @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
    
      constructor(public service: BudgetService) { }
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.getAllReports();
         this.doFilter(filterValue);
      }
    
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      }
    
      doFilter(filterValue: string) {
        this.dataSource.filter((data) => data.name!== filterValue);
      }
```

Comment: This won't work in Angular 7 (not sure of later versions) because MatTableDataSource.filter property is a string, see the error below:
(property) MatTableDataSource<User>.filter: string
Filter term that should be used to filter out objects from the data array. To override how data objects match to this filter string, provide a custom function for filterPredicate.

This expression is not callable.
  Type 'String' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

Answer (score 1):

use this function :

```
applyFilter(event: Event) {
      const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
      this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    }
```